# No content is loaded on custom customer tab / Content file not loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

**The problem:** I have a scenario where I need my customer to have an extra tab in their account settings panel (left sidebar). The content of this tab should be defined in **/app/design/frontend/$namespace/$template/templates/atropos/customer/view.phtml**. The content of the file is currently a lot of Lorem Ipsum-text.

Here are my files:

**local.xml** */app/design/frontend/$namespace/$template/layout/local.xml*

```
<layout>
...
    <customer_account>        
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">           
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="CustomerAttribute">
                <name>CustomerAttribute</name>
                <path>customerattribute/customer/view</path>
                <label>JarEinstellungen bearbeiten</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account> 


    <CustomerAttribute>
    <update handle="CustomerAttribute"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="CustomerAttribute/customer" name="view.CustomerAttribute" template="atropos/customer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </CustomerAttribute>
...
</layout>
```

I assumed that the MVC will now load the template, which is located on /app/design/frontend/$namespace/$template/template/atropos/customer/view.phtml. This is **not** the case, and also this is the problem, which I cannot sort out quiet yet.

**config.xml** */app/code/local/Atropos/CustomerAttribute/etc/config.xml*

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Atropos_CustomerAttribute>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Atropos_CustomerAttribute>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <customerattribute>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Atropos_CustomerAttribute</module>
            <frontName>customerattribute</frontName>
          </args>
      </customerattribute>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <customerattribute>
              <file>customerattribute.xml</file>
            </customerattribute>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <CustomerAttribute>
        <class>Atropos_CustomerAttribute_Helper</class>
      </CustomerAttribute>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <CustomerAttribute>
        <class>Atropos_CustomerAttribute_Block</class>
      </CustomerAttribute>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <CustomerAttribute>
        <class>Atropos_CustomerAttribute_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>customerattribute_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </CustomerAttribute>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1444918007_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Atropos_CustomerAttribute</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1444918007_setup>
      <customerattribute1444918007_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1444918007_write>
      <customerattribute1444918007_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1444918007_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

Someone might see here that I used the Magento Module Generator to get the code since I'm not a Magento Pro yet.

**Data.php** */app/code/local/Atropos/CustomerAttribute/Helper/Data.php*

```
<?php
class Atropos_CustomerAttribute_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**CustomerController.php** */app/code/local/Atropos/CustomerAttribute/controllers/CustomerController.php*

```
<?php
class Atropos_CustomerAttribute_CustomerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{   
    /**
     * Checking if user is logged in or not
     * If not logged in then redirect to customer login
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);

        // adding message in customer login page
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customerattribute')->__('Please sign in or create a new account'));
        }
    }           

    /**
     * View Your Module
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {                   
    $this->loadLayout();        
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('JarEinstellungen bearbeiten'));       
    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

My Question is now: what did I've done wrong. Any typo error? I can't see anything here. Again, I'm by far not experienced with Magento, just doing baby steps to become Marius.

I would appreciate any helpful tips! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you missed the `router` for frontend add if outside of `global` tag

```
<frontend>
            <routers>
                <CustomerAttribute>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Atropos_CustomerAttribute</module>
                        <frontName>customerattribute</frontName>
                    </args>
                </CustomerAttribute>
            </routers>

        </frontend>
```

Comment: Oh, no no its there. I'll update the original code, pls wait.

Comment: Dear Qaisar, can you please recheck your answer? That would mean a lot to me, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: i will sort this for you today

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? :)

Comment: not now did not tried yet can you paste your all files

Comment: I will recheck but iirc I posted everything in the question already.

Comment: module file are not there config.xml complete